# Synthetic control method based on several treated units

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, inference, causality

I am trying to causally evaluate an impact of a specific labor policy that was implemented in three U.S. states. I wonder if constructing a synthetic/artificial control method (SCM) for those states makes sense to resemble the treatment group?
Specifically, based on my reading of econ/policy research that uses SCM, the authors often only compare one treatment group to a set of artificial/synthetic states as in the famous California Tobacco tax [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2009.ap08746).

Therefore, I am curious if SCM can be still used in a setting where the treatment group consists of different geographic regions (e.g. three states)?

Comment: It leaves open the question of ecological fallacy if you're simply looking at state-level effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be fine. To quote Abadie (2021) [Using Synthetic Controls:
Feasibility, Data Requirements, and Methodological Aspects](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jel.20191450): "*The synthetic control framework can easily accommodate estimation with multiple treated units by fitting separate synthetic controls for each of the treated units.*" Section 8 "*Extensions and Related Methods*" in that paper comments on this further. What is a bit of an open question is whether aggregated outcomes are of interest (i.e. are we going to average the three treatment states in the OP's example) or is it a "non-sensical" view? Abadie & L'Hour (2019)[A Penalized Synthetic Control Estimator for Disaggregated Data](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2021.1971535) focus on that question in particular.

Aside from Abadie's immediate work, there a couple of well-cited references particularly on this matter: [Generalized Synthetic Controls](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-analysis/article/generalized-synthetic-control-method-causal-inference-with-interactive-fixed-effects-models/B63A8BD7C239DD4141C67DA10CD0E4F3) (2017) by Xu and [Examination of the Synthetic Control Method for Evaluating Health Policies with Multiple Treated Units](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hec.3258) (2016) by Kreif et al. Especially Xu (2017) focused on heterogeneous causal effects as it is now a more realistic question as we are looking at multiple individual treated units.

As there is an `r` tag here, it is worth mentioning that Xu's methodology is implemented in the R package [`gsynth`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsynth/index.html) but to that extent, R has quite a few packages for heterogenous treatment effect estimation if one wishes to try different approaches (e.g. [`scpi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scpi/index.html) [`hettx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hettx/), [`bartCause`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bartCause/), etc.).

Comment: This is an extremely useful and thorough answer! I appreciate you discussing the crucial point on whether it makes sense to average the treatment units and then using that to construct a synthetic group.

Comment: Cool, I am happy I could help.